# I've searched through many posts about using jquery :visible, looking to see if anyone has had conflicts when there's a <label for=""> involved

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label, hide, visible

I am using jquery to show/hide more info when a user selects a radio option. It's a simple concept - when the user clicks within the < dt > tag (i.e., they click either the < input > or < label >) the < dd > slides and stays open to display more information. Clicking within the < dt > tag again closes the < dd >.

I've successfully used this show/hide script in the past, but never with the inclusion of input or label tags. By adding a label with the for= parameter, I get issues:

If you click the radio , the slide opens fine and remains open, but click the label area and the slide opens and immediately bounces closed. In trying to debug, I found if i change or remove the for= to not match the correct id of the radio button (e.g., < input type="radio" id="option01" > < label for="" >), the slide will no longer bounce open to closed, but alas, then I'd be sacrificing accessibility by removing the for=.

Any thoughts on keeping this structure, or close to it, and not dealing with the bounce close effect?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.serviceOption').find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').click(function() {
    var moreInfo = $(this).next();
    if (moreInfo.is(':visible')) {
        moreInfo.slideUp();
    } else {
        moreInfo.slideDown('slow');
    }
   });
});

<dl class="serviceOption">  
    <dt>
        <input type="radio" name="serviceOptions" id="option01" value="value01">
        <label for="option01">Option 1</label>
    </dt>  
    <dd>Show more information on Option 1</dd>
    <dt>
        <input type="radio" name="serviceOptions" id="option02" value="value02">
        <label for="option02">Option 2</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>Show more information on Option 2</dd>
</dl>
```

Here's an example jsFiddle....

http://jsfiddle.net/8JjvT/

Clicking the radio buttons opens and closes the `dd` correctly.  Try clicking the labels to see the problem.  It opens and closes immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I stand corrected: apparently, labels with for= do have issues with click events!

See this answer: [jQuery Click fires twice when clicking on label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238599/jquery-click-fires-twice-when-clicking-on-label)

Now, taking that into account, we have to make a decision... the only way I could get it to work properly was to bind the click event to the input field, not the dt.

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/X9pNY/

```
// get all the input items from the dt's
var terms = $(".serviceOption dt input");
// attach a click handler, pass in the event
terms.click(function (evt) {
    // store the clicked item's closest dt
    var clickedDT = $(this).closest("dt");
    // if there are visible dd's
    if ($("dd:visible").length > 0) {
        // hide them
        $("dd:visible").slideUp(400, function () {
            // May not need to put this inside the callback, 
            // now that I know it was label's fault
            $(clickedDT).next("dd").slideDown();
        });
    } else {
        // otherwise, just show the nearest dd
        $(clickedDT).next("dd").slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: That solves an issue that he didn't raise, but it doesn't help with the issue that he has raised.  Try the fiddle example I added to see the real problem.

Comment: This is great, thankyou. Regarding arcane... yes, let's being a victim of cutting and pasting old code

Comment: Targeting the input absolutely is the way to go.

Comment: Glad that worked for you! As for the "arcane" comment, sorry, wasn't trying to be rude; it was definitely one of the more convoluted chains that I'd seen in awhile! :)

Comment: Don't worry, no rudeness perceived! It was a good check for me to ensure that code I first wrote years ago when i was learning is optimized for today.