# JQuery trigger function triggers multiple times

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").select(function(){
    $("input").after("Text selected ");
  });
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("input").trigger("select");
    //$('input')[0].select();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Hello World" />
<br/>
<button>Trigger select event</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above triggers select handler 3 times in chrome... That is 3 pieces of 'Text selected' appear.. I don't know why. How to fix this? 
By the way, if I use the commented way instead, still two pieces would appear. Why?

Comment: seems like a chrome bug...works fine in FF and IE

Comment: It's the same situation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238599/jquery-click-fires-twice-when-clicking-on-label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a custom event due to the fact that you are doing two things here.  To do this for a given element, I added a class (just to make it specific to text input I also added that type). (avoids the button input type)

Adjusted markup:

```
<input type="text" class="textentry" name="FirstName" value="Hello World" />
<br/>
<button>Trigger select event</button>
```

Adjusted code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.textentry[type=text]").on('textselect',function () {
      $("input.textentry[type=text]").select().after("Text selected ");
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("input.textentry[type=text]").trigger("textselect");
    });
});
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/gf6rycao/

NOTE the shortcut for this would be to only do:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("input.textentry[type=text]").select().after('TextSelected');
});
```

Note on `[type=text]` I used that rather than `:text` to allow the potential use of the performance gain of `querySelectorAll()` in the library

Comment: Putting in this way works fine when I click the button. Desired thing happens. However, nothing happens when I select the text manually. That is it is still incomplete...

Answer (score 2):

This is little bit surprising. It occurs not only in Chrome. But also in Safari and Opera too.

**Solution 1:**

My suggestion for you is `return false;`. Because in this case `select` event handler must return false. So that we can stop executing the further `select` event handlers. But calling `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` will not accomplish this. Because here there is no parent-child relationship for event bubbling.

Try this code snippets:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").select(function () {
                $("input").after("Text selected ");
                return false;
            });
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("input").trigger("select");
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Hello World" />
<br />
<button>Trigger select event</button>
```

**Solution 2:** (As per your requirement)

Try with `.on()` and `.off()` method. It will do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").on('select', appendWord);

            $("button").click(function () {
                $("input").trigger('select');
                $("input").off('select');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("input").on('select', appendWord);
                }, 300);
            });

            function appendWord() {
                $("input").after("Text selected ");
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Hello World" />
<br />
<button>Trigger select event</button>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try solution 2 which meets your requirement.

Comment: "*Calling `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` will not accomplish this.*" vs "*But `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` will also do the trick.*" - which one is it now?

Comment: @Bergi Updated the content. I couldn't remember exactly for what reason I've mentioned it. It might be due to some other's discussion. Anyway thank you for letting me to know.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but I fixed this with e.preventDefault();
maybe when it selects text it fires event again.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("input").on('select', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).after("Text selected ");
  });
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("input").select();
    //$('input')[0].select();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Hello World" />
<br/>
<button>Trigger select event</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input").on('focus',function(){
      $("input").after("Text selected ");
   });
   $("button").click(function(){
      $("input").trigger("focus");
   });
});
```