# Why does click for toggle checkbox become a double click?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am currently making a `checkbox` with a `label` attached to it. I use the `for` attribute to link the click for the checkbox.

I also have a jQuery function which `onclick` for the checkbox and labels container does a slide toggle for a text input field.

When I click the checkbox, only one click is detected and the text field slides down nicely. However, when I click the label it seems that a double click is happening so the text field slides down and then immediately back up.

I have an ID of `toggle-checkbox` on my checkbox and a `for="toggle-checkbox"` on my label and I suspect that somehow triggers an extra click.

HTML:

```
<div class="cart-summary__coupon-code">
  <div class="form-group js-coupon-code">
    <input class="cart-summary__coupon-code__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="toggle-checkbox">
    <label class="cart-summary__coupon-code__label form-group__label--block" for="toggle-checkbox">click me</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="coupon-code">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery('.js-coupon-code').click(function() {
    $( ".coupon-code" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.coupon-code {
  display: none;
}
```

I have [created a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyBqXa) where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Check this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13756844/3582159 (Duplicate?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `for="toggle-checkbox"` in the `label` when you click `label` it also fire click on the `checkbox`. So the click event of the parent fires twice for event bubbling. Use click event for the `checkbox` instead of `.js-coupon-code`.

```js
jQuery('#toggle-checkbox').click(function() {
    $(".coupon-code").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
});
```

```css
.coupon-code {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-summary__coupon-code">
  <div class="form-group js-coupon-code">
    <input class="cart-summary__coupon-code__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="toggle-checkbox">
    <label class="cart-summary__coupon-code__label form-group__label--block" for="toggle-checkbox">click me</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="coupon-code">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `preventDefault()`

```
//toggle promo code input field
jQuery('.js-coupon-code').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $( ".coupon-code" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change event from `click` to checkbox `change`.

```
jQuery('.cart-summary__coupon-code__checkbox').change(function() {
    $( ".coupon-code" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    });
});
```

Here's fixed [codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrKXxz)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can bind `click` event for `input#toggle-checkbox`. It will be applicable for its corresponding `label` too.

**Note:** Why I am telling this, in your sample you just try to click between the `checkbox` and `label`, your toggle operation will occur.

Check this example:

```js
jQuery('#toggle-checkbox').click(function() {
  $(".coupon-code").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
});
```

```css
.coupon-code {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-summary__coupon-code">
  <div class="form-group js-coupon-code">
    <input class="cart-summary__coupon-code__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="toggle-checkbox">
    <label class="cart-summary__coupon-code__label form-group__label--block" for="toggle-checkbox">click me</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="coupon-code">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```