# Javascript click event firing twice, even with stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a set of items like this:

```
<label for="Cadenza-1" class="cars">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" alt="Cadenza" id="Cadenza-1" name="vehicles[]">
    <img src="img/bill_murray_173x173.jpg">
    <span>Cadenza</span>
</label>
```

there's about 13 of them. I want to add a class to the label when clicked. However, the click event fires twice. right now I'm debugging the click event then I'll add the class:

```
var cars = document.getElementsByClassName('cars');

for(var c = 0;c < cars.length; c++){
    cars[c].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        selectVehicle(cars[c],e);
    },false);
}

function selectVehicle(el,e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

The `console.log` fires twice.

Comment: A label already has a click event (I believe).

Comment: The `.stopPropagation()` method prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM. Unless you've got other event handlers bound to containing elements for your `<label>` blocks, it won't really do anything.

Comment: Do all the `<input>` elements involved have unique id values?

Comment: Also, when running your code (https://jsfiddle.net/wxmuuoam/) It only triggers once on a click..

Comment: I guess you might have registered your event twice.

Comment: `cars[c].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        selectVehicle(cars[c],e);
 },false);` -- this probably doesn't do what you expect it to do, btw.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding preventDefault after your stopPropogation:

```
function selectVehicle(el,e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I believe it is best to place console.log(e) after the stopPropogation & preventDefault though. You will also then need to implement functionality to set the checkbox to checked since this would prevent that from happening.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I adjusted to look at the image being clicked instead to avoid the `preventDefault()` issue.

Comment: I'll accept your answer once the timer has ran out.

Answer (score 7):

When the `<span>` or the `<img>` receives a "click" event, that'll bubble up the DOM to the `<label>` element, and your event handler will be called. The `<label>` then triggers *another* "click" event on the `<input>` element, and that also bubbles up to the `<label>`.

You can check in the handler to see whether the `<input>` was clicked:

```
function selectVehicle(el,e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "INPUT") return;

    // do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, you could just add the "click" handler only to the `<input>` itself.

Now you're also going to notice that your code isn't working because you've hit a common problem with binding event handlers inside loops. The problem is that the variable `c` will have as its value the length of the `cars` list by the time the event handlers actually run. There are a few ways of dealing with that; one is to loop with `forEach()` instead of a `for` loop:

```
[].forEach.call(cars, function(car) {
    car.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        selectVehicle(car,e);
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Processing only the relevant tag name is _exactly_ the right thing to do!

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the event listener to the label, you should add the event listener to the checkbox because the label behavior copy the same of the input assigned in **for**.

Please note that if you click just in the checkbox the callbacks works fine, this is because the event on the label is raised by the checkbox.

The right way to do that is to add the event listener only for the checkbox or adding prevent default in the setlectVehicle callback.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to preventDefault or stopPropagation, but just to add listner on the input element.

> cars[c].children[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {

Try this. It is working as expected.

Additionally, you are not required to use Id's with label's for if the label element encloses the required input/other elements

```js
var cars = document.getElementsByClassName('cars');

for (var c = 0; c < cars.length; c++) {
  cars[c].children[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    selectVehicle(cars[c], e);
  }, false);
}

function selectVehicle(el, e) {
  console.log(e);

}
```

```html
<label class="cars">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" alt="Cadenza" name="vehicles[]">
  <img src="img/bill_murray_173x173.jpg">
  <span>Cadenza</span>
</label>
<label class="cars">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" alt="Cadenza" name="vehicles[]">
  <img src="img/bill_murray_173x173.jpg">
  <span>Cadenza 2</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply leave your javascript code as it is. and put the input element  outside the label like this:

```
<label for="Cadenza-1" class="cars">
       <img src="img/bill_murray_173x173.jpg">
       <span>Cadenza</span>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" alt="Cadenza" adenza-1" name="vehicles[]">
```

And this is your Javascript **UNTOUCHED**:

```
var cars = document.getElementsByClassName('cars');

for(var c = 0;c < cars.length; c++){
    cars[c].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        selectVehicle(cars[c],e);
    },false);
}

function selectVehicle(el,e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt explain the issue in the original question, but may help someone (who is as daft as me).

Using react, I always try to add an event listener in a useEffect hook, so I can utilize the cleanup function to remove the listener. In this case, I had actually added an *extra* event listener in the cleanup rather than removing it.

e.g. I had:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handler() {}

  window.addEventListener('click', handler);

  return () => {
    window.addEventListener('click', handler);
  }
})
```

The cleanup function should obviously call the `removeEventListener` function.

```
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('click', handler);
  }
```