# Eventlistener fires too many GA4 events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-listener

I used to have a eventlistener that looks something like this:

```
<script>document.querySelectorAll('.myclass').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {

gtag('event', 'phoneclick', {
  'event_category' : 'contact',
  'event_label' : 'phone'
});
});
})</script>
```

Somehow it fires the event two times. First I thought it was because the class was used more than once. But actually the class is only used for one element on the page.

I am new to this topic, so a beginners-guide would help me a big deal!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

0. Using gtag to send events is not the best practice. I would suggest getting rid of your whole event listener with whatever's inside and use GTM to properly track events.
1. How did you check that the event fires twice? Show a network tab screenshot. As well as a dataLayer screenshot.
2. Do some proper debugging: add a console.log to the callback, see if it fires twice too.
3. Use preventDefault and stopPropagation. Also try looking for existing answers: [Javascript click event firing twice, even with stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461855/javascript-click-event-firing-twice-even-with-stoppropagation)

Comment: I am very sorry.
Thank you very much for you answer! With the help of the callback - we realised, that the code itself is not false as it was still sent only once. We think the error lays on the side of Google.

Comment: Sadly we can't use the GTM .

Comment: check the network tab, make sure both hits to google have the same status code and it's not just a reidirection. Also test it in incognito to make sure it's not some debugging plugin redirecting calls like Adobe's AEP debugger likes to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the element `.myclass` only has one at the page, maybe try add a event listener as this,

```
document.querySelector('.myclass').addEventListener("click", function() { 

gtag('event', 'phoneclick', {
  'event_category' : 'contact',
  'event_label' : 'phone'
});

});
```