# Clicking on input's label triggers two clicks

Tags: javascript, html

Working with an input the following behaviour has been discovered. When the label is attached to the input with `for` attribute two click events will happen. Can someone please explain the behaviour of this "anomaly".

And if there a way to prevent the click happening on input if only the label was clicked, of course besides removing the `for` attribute.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, onClick)

var counter = 0;

function onClick(event) {
  ++counter
  console.log(counter)
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>
<label for='input'>I belong to input</label>
<label>I belong to no one</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A click is processed for both elements.

```
document.addEventListener(`click`, onClick)

var counter = 0;

function onClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ++counter
  console.log(counter)
}
```

Comment: You assign processing of a click to the entire document, and processing will be performed on each element that you clicked on. The element label processes the click and send the click processing to its element from the attribute for. To prevent further processing of the current click, you must run the preventDefault event method.

Comment: Spasibo vam ogromnoe! :)

Comment: volna     De nada :)

Answer (score 3):

The first click is related to the label, the second to the associated input. As you can see, after clicking the label, the focus is set on the input. If you remove the input, the 2nd click won't be triggered. It's the normal behavior of the browser.

You can prevent this with `event.preventDefault();`.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, onClick)

var counter = 0;

function onClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ++counter;
  console.log(counter);
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>
<label for='input'>I belong to input</label>
<label>I belong to no one</label>
```

Comment: Alexandre, thank you for you answer and for the edit you've made ;)

Answer (score 2):

The label is a nested item, each item will trigger the event.

A simular question on how to prevent it, is already answered [here] ([jQuery Click fires twice when clicking on label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238599/jquery-click-fires-twice-when-clicking-on-label))

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the `click` for the next item it will trigger click by default, which is `input` element in your case. But note that this will prevent click for all the elements in chain, which will eventually block the `click` chain which you may require for other elements.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, onClick)

var counter = 0;

function onClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ++counter
  console.log(counter)
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>
<label for='input'>I belong to input</label>
<label>I belong to no one</label>
```

Comment: @volna glad to help. You can tick mark the answer if it helped you :)